# Jquery - total quantity entered should not exceed the current value

Tags: html, jquery

Need to prevent the user from entering more than the existing quantity. It should check the total quantities entered on change event as well as on submit click.

For example, the first row(Part 1) has 50 quantities when the user is adding rows and the total quantities entered against "Part 1" should not exceed 50 and a text should display above the row. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form name="req" method="post">

<table id="exampleTbl">  
    <tr>
        <td>Part 1</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="50"></td>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
       </td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Part 2</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="100"></td>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
       </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#exampleTbl').delegate('button.addRow', 'click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
    var html = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content
    
    let btn = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" title="Click to remove">Remove</a>');
    btn.click(function () {
      $(html).remove(); // Remove row on click
    })
    
    $(html).find('.addRow').replaceWith(btn);
  });
});
```

Comment: What did you try? I see no attempt at doing what you describe in your code. Also please note that any validation done client-side is NOT real validation. If data integrity is important to you (and most of the time, it should be) you should validate inputs server-side also. Client-side validation is only for UX

Comment: @LaurentS.Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried with this: $(document).on("change", "input", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input").each(function(){
     sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    if(sum > qty){
                    $(this).before('<div class="alert alert-danger total_qty_entered" role="alert">Total Quantity should not exceed '+qty+'</div>');
    }

   });

Comment: But didn't work as expected

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: You need to check quantity total of cloned row against original row ?

Comment: Need to sum the cloned rows + the quantity of the row which they selected. For example, if the user add rows from the first row, the modified quantity of the first row + cloned rows quantity should not exceed the original quantity(50).

Comment: `original quantity(50)` user cannot change only the row which user has added can be modified ? because if user change `original quantity(50)` then  how you would come to know that only `50` allowed ?  I hope you are getting what i am trying to say ..

Comment: user can change the first row quantity. The changed quantity of the first row + dynamically added quantities should check with the original quantity.

Comment: I can add one more column to show the original quantity. So that the user will come to know the original quantity when they are modifying or adding rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below code snippet i have given **class** to your trs to differentiate them with original quantity and the quantity which user can change . Also , whenever user will change input then we need find sum of all quantity of `Part 1` or `Part 2` .So , i have use `tr` class which will have either `Part 1` or `Part 2` to iterate over trs input .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#exampleTbl').delegate('button.addRow', 'click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
    var html = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content
    let btn = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" title="Click to remove">Remove</a>');
    btn.click(function() {
      $(html).remove(); // Remove row on click
    })
    $(html).find('.addRow').replaceWith(btn);
  });
});

$(document).on("change", "input", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".total_qty_entered").remove(); //remove div
  var name = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class'); //get class 
  //get original quantity
  var qty = $("." + name + "_original").find('td:eq(2)').text();
  //loop through tr with same class > inputs
  $("." + name + " input[name=quantity]").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  console.log("Quantity : " + qty + " | Sum : " + sum)
  if (sum > qty) {
    $(this).before('<div class="alert alert-danger total_qty_entered" role="alert">Total Quantity should not exceed ' + qty + '</div>');
  }
});
//call when on submit
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var result = true;
  $("tr[data-value ='original']").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var qty = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var new_name = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var sum = 0;
    $("." + new_name + " input[name=quantity]").each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    console.log("Name : " +name+ " Sum : "+sum + " || Qty :   " + qty)
    if (sum > qty) {
      //do something 
      alert("please check quanity is greater for "+name)
      result = false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="req" method="post" onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction(event)">

  <table id="exampleTbl">
    <!--added this class-->
    <tr data-value="original" class="Part1_original">
      <td>Part 1 </td>
      <td>Original Quantity : </td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <!--added this class-->
    <tr class="Part1">
      <td>Part 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="50"></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-value="original" class="Part2_original">
      <td>Part 2</td>
      <td>Original Quantity : </td>
      <td>100</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="Part2">
      <td>Part 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="100"></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Update 1** :

You can give class to your input so that it can use in `each` to iterate over the inputs having same class and check if against the total quantity .

**Demo code** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#exampleTbl').delegate('button.addRow', 'click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
    var html = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content
    let btn = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" title="Click to remove">Remove</a>');
    btn.click(function() {
      $(html).remove(); // Remove row on click
    })
    $(html).find('.addRow').replaceWith(btn);
  });
});

$(document).on("change", "input", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  //get total quantity
  var qty = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text(); //get class 
  var name = $(this).attr('class'); //get class
  //loop through tr with same class > inputs
  $("tr > td input[class=" + name + "]").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $(".total_qty_entered").remove(); //remove div
  if (sum > qty) {
    $(this).before('<div class="alert alert-danger total_qty_entered" role="alert">Total Quantity should not exceed ' + qty + '</div>');
  }
});
//call when on submit
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var result = true;
  //loop through td input
  $("tr > td input").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('class');
    var qty = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text(); //get class 
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through all inputs with same class
    $("." + name).each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    if (sum > qty) {
      //do something 
      $(this).before('<div class="alert alert-danger total_qty_entered" role="alert">Total Quantity should not exceed ' + qty + '</div>');
      result = false;
    }

  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="req" method="post" onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction(event)">

  <table id="exampleTbl">

    <tr>
      <td>Part 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="50" class="Part1"></td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Part 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="100" class="Part2"></td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The initial rows are generated based on the database table row count. The initial rows quantity value also displaying from the db.

Comment: So everytime the row count will be different. Will it affect with your code?

Comment: This is just a demo code according to your provided html ..? what doesn't work here ? you don't need extra row for displaying quantity ?

Comment: What I mean is the initial rows( now 2) are generated dynamically based on the rows available in database. Sometimes it may go upto 15 rows. Is this code flexible for that? I saw the  classes (Part1, Part2, Part1_original, Part2_original) added manually that's why I asked.

Comment: Yes .. test at your end let me know if that didn't work for you . Or if you need to change structure of table etc.

Comment: Hi Swati, It's not working. Can we change the table structure? I can print the quantity value from the database next to the textbox to notify the user about the quantity limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219854/discussion-between-swati-and-ubs0305).